# Specifying a different temp directory for building install4j

Tags: install4j

When building on my linux machine, I notice that install4j creates directories in my /tmp directory. Unfortunately since my /tmp directory is on a small partition, it fills up quickly. Is there a variable I can specify to have these directories and files be in a different directory than /tmp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit `bin/install4j.vmoptions` and add

```
-Djava.io.tmpdir=[path to temp dir]
```

on a new line.